# What is "Berger's isembolic inequality"?

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry

Googled the name, but almost all result pointed to Berger's preprint.
Is there any reference for this?

Comment: Perhaps http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.1580 could help?

Comment: yes, that is for dimension 2. I want to know the high dimension. Gromov has a non-sharp version in his Filling Riemannian manifold paper, so I want to know whether Berger has sharp version for high dimension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Chris Croke's 2007 paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2008-136-02/S0002-9939-07-09079-X/S0002-9939-07-09079-X.pdf) for all you ever wanted to know.